# Problem with automated data storing during raster::crop (‘legend’ is not a slot in class “RasterStack”)

Tags: raster, r, clip, data-storage

I am working with a set of raster layers containing [CHIRPS monthly rainfall amounts over Africa](ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_monthly/tifs/). For purposes of reproducing the below code, I staged the decompressed tif files on 
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt1fzj9xb50jary/chirps.zip?dl=0).

Now, let's say I want to crop the stacked images by a given geographic extent. 
Here's the referring code.

```
## file import
library(raster)

ch_fls_chirps <- list.files("path/to/tif", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)
rst_chirps <- stack(ch_fls_chirps)

## desired extent (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
ext <- extent(c(37, 37.7, -3.4, -2.84))

## cropping (with output storage)
rst_chirps <- crop(rst_chirps, ext, snap = "out", 
                   filename = "path/to/tif/CRP", 
                   bylayer = TRUE, suffix = names(rst_chirps), 
                   format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

When performing `raster::crop`, the following error message is thrown:

```
Error in checkAtAssignment("RasterStack", "legend", ".RasterLegend") :  
‘legend’ is not a slot in class “RasterStack”
```

By contrast, the code works just fine when output storage is omitted during `raster::crop` and manually done afterwards.

```
## cropping (without output storage)
rst_chirps <- crop(rst_chirps, ext, snap = "out")
rst_chirps <- writeRaster(rst_chirps, filename = "path/to/tif/CRP"), 
                          bylayer = TRUE, suffix = names(rst_chirps), 
                          format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Can anybody tell me what the issue with direct output storage from within the 
`crop` command is all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug. I have fixed it in 'raster' version 2.4-21.

Comment: Maybe you should add that you are one of the developers of the `raster` package.

Comment: I had the same problem even with version 2.4-21

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The above code works with **raster** 2.5-2. Thanks again!